# Android: MaterialButton override textColor in Style

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I want to define an alternative Button Style that uses my secondaryColor as background and the `?colorOnSecondary` respectively for the text.

But I'm struggling to get the textColor defined in a style.
The MaterialButton is using a (private) selector-drawable for the textColor which uses `?colorOnPrimary`.
So this is cumbersome to override.

Is there another way to set the color without the selectorDrawable?

Comment: i suggest you to create your own selectors with your colors for button text and background and to create a style for your button with this two seletor for background and textcolor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to override the colors only for the buttons, you can use the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute(it requires the version 1.1.0).
Something like:

```
  <style name="MyButtonTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ButtonStyleTextColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ButtonStyleTextColor">
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">....</item>
    .....
  </style>
```

**Otherwise you can define a custom style**:

```
<style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
  <item name="backgroundTint">@color/my_bg_color_selector</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_text_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

Where `my_bg_color_selector.xml` can be something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/..." android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/..."/>
</selector>
```

and `my_text_color_selector.xml` can be:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/..." android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="@color/..."/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid defining a selectorDrawable - the `materialThemeOverlay` worked. My problem was that I applied a ThemeOverlay as style/theme in the view, which is not working.

Comment: Seems like there's little caveat:
Referencing a themeAttribute in the Overlay is not working.
Having:
<style name="SecondaryButtonOverlay">
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">?colorOnSecondary</item> (which again references ?textColorPrimary)
        <item name="colorPrimary">?colorSecondary</item>
    </style>

The text color is not working here. Intrestingly it is shown properly in the Android Studio Preview :/

Comment: The default selector for the textcolor uses `?attr/colorOnSurface`.

Comment: I was having the issue, if i'd specify 
<item name="colorOnPrimary">?colorOnSecondary</item>
it would not work - as the referenced color (colorOnSecondary) itself was referencing ?textColorSecondary.
It started working, when i set the colorOnSecondary to a hex-value