# On a button, text and drawable are too far away when centered

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

when I make a button width match parent, the drawable start and text are too far away, and they don't seem to respect `android:drawablePadding` setting. I tried as well with `android:gravity="center"` and `android:textAlignment="center"` to no avail. Setting some `paddingStart/End` affect indirectly how close they are to each other.
See the result below:

[image: match parent width button]

The code for button:

```
<Button
            style="@style/ActionButton.Primary.Light.Large"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_filter_and_sort_white"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Apply filters"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/someViewBelow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/someViewAbove" />
```

the style defines `background`, `textColor`, `margins`, `minDimensions`, `paddings`, `radiuses`, `textSize`, `textAllCaps`, `radiuses`, `stateListAnimator`, `fontPath` - so nothing that should affect what I'm looking for.

Comment: Play with `android:drawablePadding=" "`. You may need to set a negative value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I minimize space between text and image in button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156472/how-do-i-minimize-space-between-text-and-image-in-button)

Comment: @JohnJoe using negative padding is quite unreliable, I would say, for different screen sizes. Also, just the text is altered by `gravity`, so I've no way to have both drawable/icon and text centered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) with `app:iconGravity="start"` and defining the padding between the icon and the text with the **`app:iconPadding`** attribute.

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/...."
        app:iconGravity="start"
        app:iconPadding="..."
```

This value can be negative.

[image]

Otherwise you can use **`app:iconGravity="textStart"`**.
Here the difference of using `start` and `textStart` as `iconGravity`.

[image]

Comment: this almost work. I just need to figure out how to apply selector for background colour and not make the icon disappear, but that's obviously completely different question.

Comment: @Antek For the backgroundColor use the `app:backgroundTint`or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303790/android-materialbutton-override-textcolor-in-style/58304451#58304451).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MaterialButton now which lets setting the icon gravity `ex:app:iconGravity="textStart"`.

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#fc0"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_and_sort_white"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="10dp"
        app:iconTint="#f00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/someViewBelow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/someViewAbove"
        tools:text="Download Pdf" />
```

Add dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225040/2131915)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use android:textAlignment="textStart"?

Comment: I edited the question. It does help a little bit, but then all elements are towards start edge of the button, and what I'm after is to have both close and centered

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, it should work.

```
<Button
        style="@style/ActionButton.Primary.Light.Large"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_filter_and_sort_white"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="Apply filters"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/someViewBelow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/someViewAbove" />
```